# Change PS1 after running the 'script' command

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I am looking to create a logging system for every command and some timestamps.

I think the "script" command would be the best because you get a log of the input and output.

Now the problem is when I start the script command the `PS1` (the command line prompt, which shows the user and `PWD`) gets changed from:

```
PS1=`echo $LOGNAME`@`hostname`:'$PWD# '
```

to

```
PS1=\s-\v\$
```

and I can't see to get it to switch back. I have tried to change it in both `/etc/profile` (where the script command is called) and in the users directory `/home/.profile`. But when I `su -` to the user to start the logging it still is wrong.

Comment: `PS1` is generally set in `~/.bashrc` on a per-user basis. (e.g. `~/.profile` is generally only called for *login* shells, while `~/.bashrc` is called for every *interactive* shell.)

Comment: I have tried to modify the ~/.bashrc but still no sucess!
The thing is when i su - I start a subshell... And when the script command runs it starts a subshell again. And I have no idea where that config file is, the command prompt is set to "$" in ksh and \s-\v\$ in bash

Comment: You could always save the prompt before calling `script` and restore it afterwards. e.g. `echo "PS1='$PS1'" >/tmp/myps1` run your `script` then after it completes `. /tmp/myps1` to source the original prompt.